# Sliding crosses in a 3x3 grid

Tags: strategy

You are given a 3x3 grid with 3 crosses as shown below. Each turn, you can select a cross and slide it along horizontally or vertically. It will continue sliding until it hits another cross or a wall. Can you get a cross into the centre square?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Yes.

Consider

> |X|X|=|
>  |X|=|=|
>  |=|=|=|
>  |X|=|X|
>  |X|=|=|
>  |=|=|=|
>  |X|=|=|
>  |X|=|=|
>  |=|=|X|
>  |=|=|X|
>  |X|=|=|
>  |=|=|X|
>  |=|=|=|
>  |X|=|X|
>  |=|=|X|
>  |=|=|=|
>  |=|X|X|
>  |=|=|X|

Comment: Correct and well done! You can now try the harder version of this puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122806/sliding-crosses-in-a-4x4-grid

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible?

> Yes

> The follow 6-move sequence is the shortest I can find. No proof that it is optimal.
>  [image]

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, possible in 5 moves

> A2-A1, A1-C1, A3-A1,A1-B1,B3-B2